# Keyboard Input Not Working with WebAssembly and Emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten, webassembly

I have a basic bit of code that renders to a webgl canvas element.  When i call the event registration methods I either get no callback at all (when i specify the canvas name or #canvas as below or an error in chrome when i specify #document or #window related to not being able to register with a null object)

```
emscripten_set_keydown_callback("#canvas", nullptr, true, Platform::keyCallback);
emscripten_set_keyup_callback("#canvas", nullptr, true, Platform::keyCallback);
```

My Canvas element in html is

```
<canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" width="640px" height="480px"></canvas>
```

and my test method for input is..

```
EM_BOOL Platform::keyCallback(int eventType, const EmscriptenKeyboardEvent *keyEvent, void *userData)
{
    printf("TEST\n");
}
```

Note: printf does work as I have other output to the console.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you post your full code with the main function? It doesn't look like a problem with `emscripten_set_keydown_callback`.

Comment: Found the solution and entered it below, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was in the HTML file.  I needed to add "tabindex=-1" into the canvas. For example:

```
<canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" width="640px" height="480px" tabindex=-1></canvas>
```

As a result of this change the code now seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Shouldn't tabindex value be in double quotes: tabindex="-1"

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another answer as I found that 'tabindex=-1' wasn't enough and needed to bring the canvas object in to focus.

I achieved this by adding code similar to this:

```
addOnPostRun(function()
{
     var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
     if (canvas)
         canvas.focus();
});
```

to the postfix code specified in '--post-js ./your_postfix_file.js' when building using emcc.